# Power saw kinda got away from me there…

Tags: meaning-in-context

while I was watching Friends season 3, I saw Chandler fell down and Joey commented, "Power saw kinda got away from me there…". For that, I have also searched on the web, but I found nothing there.

What does it mean ? 
--> "Power saw kinda got away from me there…"

Comment: Please explain to us the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is [here](http://uncutfriendsepisodes.tripod.com/season3/305uncut.htm). Chandler fell because he tried opening his bedroom door, but it had been cut in half by Joey. Joey admits he did it by saying "[the] power saw kind of got away from me there", implying it was an accident.

Comment: Is it a phrase ? which kind of sentences is it ?

Comment: No, it's not a known phrase, it is a standard sentence. It is written to reflect the way Joey talks; a lot of what happens in the world bewilders him. The humour in the line is because the vast majority of people couldn't accidently and neatly cut a door in two with a power saw, but you sort of believe Joey could.

Comment: I think "X got away from me" could be considered a reasonably common phrase used to describe one having lost control of X. It can either be very literal 'the dog got away from me' or more metaphorical 'my finances got away from me'.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, "X got away from me" is, while not really "common", at least familiar to most adults in the US.  Often said sarcastically/ironically when one "goes crazy" with some tool or, say, a paint brush, doing far more "repairs" than the situation called for.  Injecting "kinda" is a strong hint (but not proof) that the statement is meant to be ironic.

(Can also be said in a non-ironic vein, when a tool does indeed "jump out of your hands" or some such and do some damage.)